# Was NASA's 2007 attempt to see helions during a solar eclipse successful? What instruments were used?

Tags: solar-eclipse, meteor, nasa, meteoroid

This [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/30066/7982) about Sun-grazing comets led me eventually to Wikipedia's [Helion (meteoroid)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helion_(meteoroid)), which has a one-sentence long article:

> A Helion meteoroid is a meteoroid that arrives from the approximate direction of the Sun. They are thought to originate as debris from sun-grazing comets.

It has one reference

> ["Exploding Lunar Eclipse", an article about an attempt to observe Helion meteoroids](https://science.nasa.gov/headlines/y2007/27aug_explodingeclipse.htm?list84849), Science@NASA, August 27, 2007.

but that link is now dead.

- Was NASA's 2007 attempt to see meteoroids coming from a solar eclipse successful? What instruments were used?
- Has it been attempted again since?

Comment: Article available in wayback machine. It got a 301 redirect for the latest version, pretty sure it is still the same address except for the parameter. https://web.archive.org/web/20120910062131/http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2007/27aug_explodingeclipse/

Comment: @bitchaser bits chased and recovered, excellent! Consider writing it up as a short answer?

Comment: It's your reference, and I'm not up to a long answer, so I'll pass.