# Could there be an eclipse tomorrow if the Pleiades is covered by the Moon tonight?

Tags: the-moon, solar-eclipse, lunar-eclipse, ecliptic

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Suppose today there is a covering of the Pleiades star cluster by the Moon. Could there be an eclipse of the sun tomorrow? The moon?

I think the answer to both is no, because Pleiades are located above the ecliptic, but I'm not sure. Could someone provide an explanation please?

Comment: Not an answer here, but there may be some helpful information in [this answer to *When are the planets occulted by the sun?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/28263/7982) There's a GIF from SOHO images of the Pleides shooting past the Sun.

Comment: Can you add some numbers to your question? What is the Pleiades' ecliptic coordinates and what is the (mean) inclination of the Moon's orbit?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider how far the pleiades are above the ecliptic, and how far the moon travels in a day.  From this you can work the angle at which the moon must travel relative to the ecliptic, in order to cross the eliptic within a day.

You can then compare this with the actual inclination of the moon's orbit to the ecliptic, and that will tell you if an eclipse is possible.